# New nginx server block parsed successfully but site can't be reached

Tags: nginx

I added the following server config in a file called "findernext-ssl.conf" both in `sites-enabled` and `sites-available` :

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl ;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;


        server_name findernext.inventivedesign.fr;



        # Redirect all non-SSL traffic to SSL.
        if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
                rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8084/finder/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'Upgrade';
                # timeout 43200000;
                # websocket_connect_timeout 43200000;
                proxy_connect_timeout 43200000;
                # so_keepalive on;
                tcp_nodelay on;
                # websocket_pass websockets;
                # websocket_buffer 1k;
         }
}
```

`sudo nginx -t` shows no parsing error. But then after restarting nginx, the site simply cannot be reached. No nginx error, it's just not found.

I actually just cloned another file called "physio-ssl.conf" which **works** and looks exactly the same only with a different sub-domain and redirection :

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl ;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;


        server_name physisolve.inventivedesign.fr;



        # Redirect all non-SSL traffic to SSL.
        if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
                rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8084/physisolve/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'Upgrade';
                # timeout 43200000;
                # websocket_connect_timeout 43200000;
                proxy_connect_timeout 43200000;
                # so_keepalive on;
                tcp_nodelay on;
                # websocket_pass websockets;
                # websocket_buffer 1k;
         }
}
```

What is going on ? Thanks.

Comment: `physisolve.inventivedesign.unistra.fr` points to `130.79.75.183` (which is the same as `inventivedesign.unistra.fr`), but `findernext.inventivedesign.unistra.fr` does not resolve.

Comment: Yep. The question is why ?

Comment: This is a DNS issue and has nothing to do with Nginx. IDK why you do not have a CNAME or A record for `findernext`.

Comment: Where should I start looking to fix it ?